# Can you make an Azure Blob Container a virtual network drive on an Azure Virtual Windows Machine?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-service

Similar to a dropbox or I guess all virtual drives?

It'd make everyone's life easier if there was an easy way to set this up.

Answer (score 2):

No (at least not out of the box), but you can map Azure Files as a network drive.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows

Comment: thanks! I came across this earlier but was wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: unfortunately not. you can use azure storage explorer